# Filter objects with random number keys in Es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an object with keys and objects. I am trying to see if I can filter out and return only the ones that match the criteria. This is the object

the random number keys will or could be different.

```
{
    "0e93e707-e5aa-4d2b-91ab-a8dec97af344": {
        "Id": "0e93e707-e5aa-4d2b-91ab-a8dec97af344",
        "ExternalSecurityListId": null,
        "CreatorId": "557fa8b2-59db-430d-9595-cd17884c9151",
        "Name": "Chris",
        "PartnerName": null,
        "Type": "Watch",
        "CostBasis": 0,
        "Processing": false,
        "NotificationSettings": {
            "SourceId": "0e93e707-e5aa-4d2b-91ab-a8dec97af344",
            "SourceType": "SecurityList",
            "ChannelTypes": null,
            "NotificationFilters": []
        },
        "Owner": null,
        "SharingStatus": "None",
        "CreatedDate": "2023-02-01T20:31:21.848Z",
        "ModifiedDate": "2023-02-10T17:12:21.053Z",
        "IsGroup": false,
        "UnderlyingSecurityListIds": [],
        "MaturingSoon": false
    },
    "ed89d5a3-464b-4bd7-b9bb-e42ee87f6520": {
        "Id": "ed89d5a3-464b-4bd7-b9bb-e42ee87f6520",
        "ExternalSecurityListId": null,
        "CreatorId": "557fa8b2-59db-430d-9595-cd17884c9151",
        "Name": "Chris Portfolio Two",
        "PartnerName": null,
        "Type": "Portfolio",
        "CostBasis": 100000,
        "Processing": false,
        "NotificationSettings": {
            "SourceId": "ed89d5a3-464b-4bd7-b9bb-e42ee87f6520",
            "SourceType": "SecurityList",
            "ChannelTypes": null,
            "NotificationFilters": []
        },
        "Owner": null,
        "SharingStatus": "None",
        "CreatedDate": "2023-03-20T19:20:02.16Z",
        "ModifiedDate": "2023-03-20T19:20:17.117Z",
        "IsGroup": false,
        "UnderlyingSecurityListIds": [],
        "MaturingSoon": false
    },

}
```

I tried filtering by key such as this but it's not returning any results.

```
const allowed = ['Portfolio'];
const filtered = Object.keys(portfoliosData)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = portfoliosData[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
const filtered = Object.keys(portfoliosData)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = portfoliosData[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to accomplish. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: what does the `allowed` variable do?

Comment: @ChrisB. I was just throwing somethings together, basically Id like to filter through the object of objects and return only the ones with "Type": "Portfolo",

Comment: @VictorSantizo same as above, just trying to return the objects what have the property of Type": "Portfolo"

Comment: Do you want to return the full objects that contain property type with value portfolio?

Comment: Is the structure of those objects always the same?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues the goal is to return all objects that match that criteria.  the structure should always stay the same

Comment: I don't see the word "portfolio" anywhere in your code. Where are you expecting to filter by it?

Comment: just portfoliosData.filter(data => allowed.includes(data.Type));

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues each object should have a property type, I am just looking for property types that equals to 'Portfolio"  `Type: Portfolio`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments, this is an option to accomplish that:

```
Object.values(portfoliosData).filter(({Type}) => Type == "Portfolio")
```

It will list only the values of the topmost object (instead of the keys), and then you iterate on filter with a lambda that captures the property Type and checks if it is equals to the expected value

Comment: @chewie If you want to generalize to check against a list of allowed values, just change `Type == "Portfolio"` into `allowed.includes(Type)`. But you are smart, you have probably already figured that out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your blob of JSON is being assigned to the `portfoliosData` variable, then `Object.keys(portfoliosData)` will return `["0e93e707-e5aa-4d2b-91ab-a8dec97af344", "ed89d5a3-464b-4bd7-b9bb-e42ee87f6520"]`.  Obviously the `allowed` array does not contain either of these keys, so your filter is (correctly) filtering out all options and returning you an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter the object dictionary into an array of `[key, object]`:

```js
const dictionary = {1: {Property: "correct"}, 2: {Property: "incorrect"}};
const correctObjects = [];
for (const key in dictionary) {
    const object = dictionary[key];
    if (object.Property === "correct") {
        correctObjects.push([key, object]);
    }
}
console.log(correctObjects);
```

Outputs: `[ ["1", {"Property":"correct"}] ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through `Object.keys(portfoliosData)` and then for each of them you would just check their portfolio type. Your `allowed` variable doesn't seem to match how you want your app to work.

```js
keys = Object.keys(portfoliosData)
filtered = []
for (k of keys) {
    if (portfoliosData[k]['Type'] == 'Portfolio') {
        filtered.push(portfoliosData[k])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `portfoliosData` is a map where keys are ids and values are the corresponding data items that have different `Type`s. You want to get a list of all items with `Type` in the `allowed` list.

You can do something like this:

`const allowedItems = Object.entries(portfolioData).filter(item => allowed.includes(item.Type))`

This approach completely disregards the keys of the `portfolioData` since they are random. `Object.values` returns the array of all items that you can filer over.

Answer (score 0):

I jus threw this together but see if this would work.

```
const result = Object.values(data).filter((item) => item.Type === 'Portfolio')
```

I put your example data into a const of data.  So just change data to whatever your source is and this should filter it.